# Repair my partitions and reinstall Grub2

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, grub2

I messed up my partitions because I wanted to increase the space for Ubuntu.
I had a boot partition between the two partitions I wanted to merge, so I tried to delete and merge the partitions and re-install grub2.
I used `gparted`.

But I am not able to re-install grub2 facing errors

> GRUB failed to install to the following devices:
>   /dev/nvme0n1

I have/had a dual-boot configuration with a partition for windows and one for Ubuntu.
I took some space from Windows partition to increase the Ubuntu partition.

```
➜  ~ blkid                                      
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1p6: UUID="f174b408-190c-42c4-9193-4fd4b4e2435f" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop17: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop18: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop19: TYPE="squashfs"
```

I tried to purge/reinstall `grub`:

```
sudo apt-get purge grub grub-pc grub-common
sudo apt-get install grub-common grub-pc
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. What do you mean with _"I had a boot partition between the two partitions I wanted to merge"_? BTW Give it a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/798500/196535) maybe it can be useful...

Comment: This what I shouldn't have done https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401002/rearrange-partitions-in-gparted-to-extend-a-partition (the partition was grub2 core.img). Thanks for your answer